# I cannot use ebean in play framework

Tags: playframework-2.4

I'm using play 2.4. I got compilation error: package "com.avaje.ebean" does not exist. Need help, appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Play's Ebean is now an external project.  You need to add a dependency in your `project/plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

In your `build.sbt` file, enable the plugin:

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

All this information and more is available in the [2.4 migration guide](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24).